# Remove all files in specific folder in Linux

Tags: linux, file-management

I have a particular group of two folders that are in many places on my CentOS server. Let's say these folders look like this:

```
aaa/bbb/cat
aaa/bbb/dog
```

The names and structure of `aaa`, `bbb`, `cat` and `dog` are fixed, but they occur in multiple places in the server. For instance:

```
/folder1/aaa/bbb/cat
/folder1/aaa/bbb/dog
/folder2/folder3/folder4/aaa/bbb/cat
/folder2/folder3/folder4/aaa/bbb/dog
etc...
```

What command can I use to delete ALL files within every instance of `cat` and `dog` on the server, but only when they are subfolders of `bbb` and `aaa` respectively, as shown above?

Thanks!

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have said, bash v4. But answers below already solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bash 4.0 you can use `shopt -s globstar`.  By default not enabled.

With your example

```
ls **/aaa/bbb/cat/*     # globstar not enabled
```

gives 
    folder1/aaa/bbb/cat/1

```
shopt -s globstar
ls **/aaa/bbb/cat/*     # globstar ENABLED
```

gives

```
folder1/aaa/bbb/cat/1  folder2/folder3/folder4/aaa/bbb/cat/3
```

This is the `tree .` of your example.

```
.
├── folder1
│   └── aaa
│       └── bbb
│           ├── cat
│           │   └── 1
│           └── dog
│               └── 1
├── folder2
│   └── folder3
│       └── folder4
│           └── aaa
│               └── bbb
│                   ├── cat
│                   │   └── 3
│                   └── dog
│                       └── 4
```

Of course you can repeat it with dog instead of cat too :-)
Check before with `ls` and remove after with `rm`.
Notes:
You have to remember to enable globstar (`shopt -s globstar`) on each new shell in which you want to use that syntax else you can put it in your `~..bash_rc` file...

Answer (score 1):

Run `find` twice

```
find . -path "*/aaa/bbb/cat/*" -delete
find . -path "*/aaa/bbb/dog/*" -delete
```

or do

```
find . \( -path "*/aaa/bbb/cat/*" -o -path "*/aaa/bbb/dog/*" \) -delete
```

Comment: Thanks for this - problem already solved, though I like how succinct your answer is.